# Is there an alternative to using if (is_single)?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm currently working on a wordpress site, where I need individual content on each single page. Specifically, I need to display certain other posts. I can't use tags and categories as they account for separate information.

```
<?php if ( is_single(548)) { ?>
  <a href="<?php echo get_tag_link(174); ?>" style="color: #000000;">Katte</a><br>
<?php } else { echo '<div class="yyy"></div>' ; } ; ?>

<!-- Post 2 -->
<?php if ( is_single(555)) { ?>
   <a href="<?php echo get_tag_link(173); ?>" style="color: #000000;">Hatte</a><br>
 <?php } else { echo '<div class="yyy"></div>' ; } ; ?>

<?php if ( is_single(555)) { ?>
   <a href="<?php echo get_tag_link(174); ?>" style="color: #000000;">Random</a><br>
<?php } else { echo '<div class="yyy"></div>' ; } ; ?>

<!-- Post 3 -->
<?php if ( is_single(561)) { ?>
   <a href="<?php echo get_category_link(110); ?>" style="color: #000000;">Random2</a>
<?php } else { echo '<div class="yyy"></div>' ; } ; ?>
```

This is a sample of the code I'm using to display specific posts, categories and tags on specific single pages. Is there any alternative that requires less coding? I'm currently at 1300 lines and it's affecting my loading speed on the pages.

Comment: To be honest, if you are not willing to use taxonomies, then no, there is no other way of doing what you are doing. Crap, 1300 line of code is totally overboard and unnecessary

Comment: I'm not positive what your end goal is, but you can use a plugin like advanced custom fields and set a relation field for individual posts. This is a little more for advanced developers so if this makes no sense then maybe doing it the way you are is your only option. I develop for WP daily, and I've had to do quite a lot. Never have I had to do what you're doing. There's always a better way.

Answer (score 1):

I'd store the other post's ID in a postmeta field and use [add_meta_box()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) to add a field to the post editor so people can edit it. Then, you can use [get_post_meta()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) to retrieve the value in your theme and display either the link or the empty div you're using as a fallback.